# Compute the pole set of a rational function defined on $\mathrm{V}(X_{1}^{2}-X_{2}^{2}+X_{3}^{2}-X_{4}^{2})$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, rational-functions

I want to answer the following question.

> Compute the pole set of the rational function $\zeta=\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{x_{3}+x_{4}}$ defined on an algebraic variety $V=\mathrm{V}(X_{1}^{2}-X_{2}^{2}+X_{3}^{2}-X_{4}^{2})\subseteq A^{4}(\mathbb{C}).$

I did the following reasoning:

The pole set is $\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\in V \text{ s. t. } x_3+x_4=0 \}$. This leads to $x_4=-x_3$, therefore $x_1^2-x_2^2+x_3^2-x_3^2=x_1^2-x_2^2=0$. So $x_1^2=x_2^2$.

Then the pole set is generated by $(x_1, \sqrt {x_1^2}, x_3, -x_3)$

Usually this kind of exercises are longer and I think that maybe I am forgetting something because it was too easy. Is this answer true?

Comment: Note that $x_3+x_4 = \frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{x_4-x_3}$ wherever this fraction is defined.

Comment: But the pole set remais the same, right?

Comment: Actually, I don't understand your answer now that I look at it. Can you write down the ideal for your pole set carefully? You seem to be writing coordinates of points.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that you are just listing the coordinates of points you claim are in the pole set. But by using my above observation, you'll see that $p=(1,-1,1,-1)$ lies in your set but is not a pole and that $\zeta(p)=-1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might be thinking something in the wrong way, as I see that $\zeta(p)=\frac{0}{0}$ so $p=(1,-1,1,-1)$ must be a pole.

Comment: Rewrite the fraction in equivalent form using my first comment.

Comment: @JohnBrevik I am sorry, I am stuck in this exercise and I need some more explicit hints. I understand that the poles must nullify the denominator of every representation of $\zeta$, but I don't know how to find them (using your first comment I think the pole set may be $\mathrm V (X_3 +X_4, X_1 ^2 - X_2 ^2 )$, but I don't know if there are more).

Comment: No, the pole set is smaller than that, not bigger. A few things: $\zeta(p)$ cannot ``equal" $\frac{0}{0}$. There is no such thing as $\frac{0}{0}$. Next, for instance, $2$ is not a pole of the "rational function" $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$. It's what you'd call a "removable singularity." Make sure you understand both of my above points. Now, by what I wrote in my first comment, we see that the two rational functions $\frac{x_1+x_2}{x_3+x_4}$ and $(x_1+x_2)\frac{x_4-x_3}{x_1^2-x_2^2} = \frac{x_4-x_3}{x_1-x_2}$ are equal everywhere they are both defined, so they define the same rational function.